# Why HighStocks ticks are calculated unevenly?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The data being passed to HighStocks is:

```
[[1505433600000,"15000.0"],
[1505692800000,"15000.0"], 
[1505779200000,"15002.4785072264849164674"],
[1505865600000,"15004.95789197307424571901"],
[1505952000000,"15007.4381546342814965765"],
[1506038400000,"15009.9192956046704969869"],
[1506297600000,"15012.40131495591828960078"]]
```

The config for the xAxis is:
`{tickWidth: 1, tickLength: 5, gridLineWidth: 0}`
Although I don't think it matters.

Finally, the result is:
[image: this]

The issue is: the points are perfectly placed and equally spaced, which is exactly what I want. The ticks, on the other hand, are weirdly uneven with the most notable being the 23/09 tick being much closer than 25/09 than it should.

The ideal here is that the ticks just follow the data points, or even that the ticks are evenly divided. That said, it isn't a matter of 'ordinal', since I don't want dates that weren't present to be displayed (weekends).

I tried messing with options and figuring it out, but I can't pinpoint why this happens. It seems it shouldn't.

Comment: Could you add a live example like JSfiddle please

Comment: @Core972 is that enough? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXqmQr

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ordinal: false` ([Link to the doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal))

Your [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwWrvE) updated to line 29 of the JS part

Comment: I think that doesn't cut it actually. This makes the chart display all dates, not just the dates from the series. It is missing weekends and I'd like to omit them. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display ticks exactly where the points are, use `tickPositions` array.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.dateFormat

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/g4uyo5q7/

Comment: Then what happens when resolution gets too small or there are too many points? Does HighCharts adapt it accordingly or it gets cramped ticks and stuff?